# Getting NPE from .equals() method of String class. How to debug this

Tags: java, collections, nullpointerexception, queue

I have been trying to solve the 752th problem of LeetCode (Open the Lock) with BFS. Now, after polling from a queue, when I'm using the variable (type String) to equate it with the target String in an if condition, I am getting an NPE.

```
    public int openLock(String[] deadends, String target) {
        int len = target.length();
        Set <String> s = new HashSet <String> (Arrays.asList(deadends));
        Queue <String> q = new LinkedList <>();
        q.add("0000");s.add("0000");
        int cnt = 0; 
        while(!q.isEmpty()){
            int size = q.size();
            while(size>0){
                String ans = q.poll(); String t="";
                if(ans.equals(target))
                    return cnt;
                if(s.contains(ans))
                    continue;
                for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--){
                    t=ans; char c = t.charAt(i);
                    if(c==target.charAt(i))
                        continue;
                    int act = c-'0';
                    int inc = (act+1)%10;
                    int dec = (act-1); 
                    if(dec<0)
                        dec=dec+10;
                    t=t.substring(0,i)+inc+t.substring(i+1); 
                    if(!s.contains(t)){
                        s.add(t);
                        q.add(t);
                    } 
                    t=ans;
                        t=t.substring(0,i)+dec+t.substring(i+1); 
                    if(!s.contains(t)){
                        s.add(t);
                        q.add(t);
                    } 
                }size--;
            }
            cnt++; 
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is pretty clear that the queue is empty at some point when you poll it, hence you end up calling `equals()` on a null string.  You need to check your logic here.

Comment: But, isn't the size counter there to precisely stop that from happening? I'm sorry, I'm new to implementing BFS through collections. I'm using the size variable to do the level order traversal and if the queue is empty, the while(!q.isEmpty()) should terminate it, I guess. And the second while loop (for traversal in each level) also has the clause size>0. So, I'm actually at a loss. I tried reversing the order as Martin suggests, but now I am getting an NPE when I'm initialising String t to ans (the string that's storing the polled value).

Comment: That's because you're manipulating the Queue inside your while loop, but you're not updating the `size` variable. If you change it to `while(q.size() > 0)` it will behave as you expect. Personally, I prefer `while(!q.isEmpty())`. It does the same but looks a little neater.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `equals` on any object where the left-hand side is `null` will throw a `NullPointerException`. The right-hand side will not throw if it's `null`. So in this case, you can avoid this by swapping the sides:

```
if(target.equals(ans))
```

Assuming `target` is never `null` of course (I'm guessing it's not). You could ensure this by adding a [*guard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)) to the start of the method.

```
if(target == null) throw new NullPointerException("Method parameter `target` should not be null")
```

It's for the same reason you commonly place `String` constants on the left-hand side as well, since you never have to worry about it being `null`. E.g.

```
if("MyAmazingConstant".equals(maybeNullVariable))
```

Or

```
const String MY_AMAZING_CONSTANT = "MyAmazingConstant"

if(MY_AMAZING_CONSTANT.equals(maybeNullVariable))
```

Or you can use something like [`StringUtils` from Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html), which has a variety of null-safe equality operators. This will also support other edge cases (e.g. both sides being `null`).

Whether `ans` should be `null` in the first place is a different question. Since you're getting the value of a `Queue` using the `poll` method, this means that the `Queue` is empty at that time.

Comment: `Assuming target is never null of course` ... you could add a check for this at the start of the method, and throw an exception if the incoming `target` be `null`.  Then, your answer would be more solid.

Comment: You're suggesting add a *guard* to the method to ensure the method parameter `target` satisfies a certain pre-conditions (not null). Good idea, I'll add it to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your bug, but this'd pass through:

```
public class Solution {
    public static final int openLock(String[] deadends, String target) {
        Set<String> startSet = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> endSet = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> deadSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(deadends));
        startSet.add("0000");
        endSet.add(target);
        int minTurns = 0;
        Set<String> tempSet;

        while (!startSet.isEmpty() && !endSet.isEmpty()) {
            if (startSet.size() > endSet.size()) {
                tempSet = startSet;
                startSet = endSet;
                endSet = tempSet;
            }

            tempSet = new HashSet<>();

            for (String start : startSet) {
                if (endSet.contains(start))
                    return minTurns;
                }

                if (deadSet.contains(start)) {
                    continue;
                }

                deadSet.add(start);
                StringBuilder startSB = new StringBuilder(start);

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    char character = startSB.charAt(i);
                    String s1 = startSB.substring(0, i) + (character == '9' ? 0 : character - '0' + 1) + startSB.substring(i + 1);
                    String s2 = startSB.substring(0, i) + (character == '0' ? 9 : character - '0' - 1) + startSB.substring(i + 1);

                    if (!deadSet.contains(s1))
                        tempSet.add(s1);
                    }

                    if (!deadSet.contains(s2)) {
                        tempSet.add(s2);
                    }
                }
            }

            minTurns++;
            startSet = tempSet;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Here is LeetCode's solution using Breadth First Search:

```
class Solution {
    public int openLock(String[] deadends, String target) {
        Set<String> dead = new HashSet();
        for (String d: deadends) dead.add(d);

        Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList();
        queue.offer("0000");
        queue.offer(null);

        Set<String> seen = new HashSet();
        seen.add("0000");

        int depth = 0;
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            String node = queue.poll();
            if (node == null) {
                depth++;
                if (queue.peek() != null)
                    queue.offer(null);
            } else if (node.equals(target)) {
                return depth;
            } else if (!dead.contains(node)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                    for (int d = -1; d <= 1; d += 2) {
                        int y = ((node.charAt(i) - '0') + d + 10) % 10;
                        String nei = node.substring(0, i) + ("" + y) + node.substring(i+1);
                        if (!seen.contains(nei)) {
                            seen.add(nei);
                            queue.offer(nei);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

You can see that there is a `queue.offer(null);`, that might be your problem.

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/open-the-lock/submissions/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

#### If you are preparing for [interviews](https://leetcode.com/problemset/top-interview-questions/?listId=wpwgkgt):

- We would want to write [bug-free](https://www.codegrip.tech/productivity/tips-to-write-bug-free-code-during-interview/) and [clean](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-write-cleaner-code-during-onsite-interviews) codes based on standards and conventions (e.g., [c](/questions/tagged/c)<sup>[1](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/cplus/cstyle.html), [2](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eeno/coding/CCodingStandard.html)</sup>, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html), [2](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards)</sup>, [java](/questions/tagged/java)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), [2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)</sup>, [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)<sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/?redirectedfrom=MSDN)</sup>, [python](/questions/tagged/python)<sup>[1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)</sup>, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)<sup>[1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)</sup>, [go](/questions/tagged/go)<sup>[1](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments)</sup>, [rust](/questions/tagged/rust)<sup>[1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/)</sup>).

Comment: How does this answer the question?